# UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified uri max length error

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

Hi I develop an UWP app that communicate with html page via Javascript send message app by using document.location.`(document.location = "toApp://PEtPTVVU....") and i catch it with webview UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified event .But problem is when i use a string more than 260 it gives error threw an exception of type` System.UriFormatException` .Is there any solution beside a kind of link shortener

Solution for me
I used alert in html and catch encoded message like that

Comment: that number of 260 sounds very familiar. Looks like MAX_PATH is at play there ....

Comment: yes i searched it .System.Uri has a limitation 260.i saw a few solution but that was in web projects. it seems there is no solution beside using short link but i wrote here with %1 hope :))